# Limiting behavior of $\left|(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (s_n-s)x^n\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, epsilon-delta

Let $-1\lt x\lt 1$, $s=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$, $\varepsilon \gt 0$ is arbitrary, there exists $N$ such that $n\gt N$ implies $|s-s_n|\gt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then
$$\left|(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (s_n-s)x^n\right|\le (1-x)\sum_{n=0}^N |s_n-s||x|^n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\le \varepsilon$$
if $x\gt 1-\delta$ for some $\delta\gt 0$.

This is based on Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, pages $174—175$.

Is that still true if we change the condition to $x\lt 1-\delta$? If we take that with the condition $-1\lt x\lt 1$, $1-x$ would still be in the desired range. Why shouldn't it be true, based on the above argument?

Comment: The first inequality holds for $-1 < x < 1$. But for the second one, you need $1 - x$ to be small (or $\lvert x\rvert$ if $s_0 = s$, but we're interested in $\lim_{x \to 1}$, so that's not useful).

Comment: @DanielFischer "you need $1-x$ to be small" If $x\lt 1-\delta$, then $1-x$ is still smaller than $1$, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, if $x$ is very close to $-1$, then $x < 1-\delta$ for small enough $\delta$, but $1 - x$ is close to $2$. But that aside, you don't just need $1 - x < 1$, you need $$(1 - x) \sum_{n = 0}^{N} \lvert s_n - s\rvert \cdot \lvert x\rvert^n \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer If we have $|1-x|\lt 1$, is that the same as the last requirement you mention? If not, what would be a counterexample?

Comment: Anything where $\frac{\varepsilon}{2\lvert s_0 - s\rvert} < 1$ is an example where $\lvert 1 - x\rvert < 1$ is not sufficient.

Comment: @DanielFischer Regarding the last inequality in my post: We want $x$ to be small (because $|s-s_n|\gt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$),  but we also want $1-x$ to be close to zero. This seems quite confusing to me. What should be chosen?

Comment: @DanielFischer I know we're looking for $\lim_{x\to 1}$, but $|1-x|\lt 1$ is not sufficient.

Comment: We do **not** want $\lvert x\rvert$ to be small. Although that would easily make the terms for $1 \leqslant n \leqslant N$ small, it wouldn't do diddly-squat for $n = 0$. So bite the bullet, use $\lvert x\rvert^n \leqslant 1$ and estimate the first part by $$(1-x)\sum_{n = 0}^{N} \lvert s_n - s\rvert\,.$$ Since $N$ is dependent only on $\varepsilon$ this can be made small by choosing $x$ close to $1$.